# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "user". Tried all answers on stackOverflow

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

please help me out. I've tried all previous answers on stack overflow for this issue and none of them are working for me.

server.js file:

```
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
connectDB();
const express = require('express');
//connecting database

const app = express();

//Initializing Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API running'));
//defining routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

default.json file:

```
{
  "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://sudarshan:15ab035tx@brunelconnector-go4lo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

config/db .js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });

    console.log('mongodb Connected ...');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

User.js file:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: { type: String },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', 'UserSchema');
```

user.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../../models/User');
const router = express.Router();
//get the user data

//express validator to validate
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post(
  '/', //express-validator validation
  [
    check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Enter a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Enter a password with 6 or more characters').isLength({
      min: 6,
    }),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    //express validator validation
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    try {
      //See if user exists
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (user) {
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Error, user already exists' }] });
      }

      console.log(req.body);
      res.send('Users route');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error lol');
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Error:

```
/Users/sudarshan/Documents/WebDev/BrunelConnector/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:502
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^

MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "user".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (/Users/sudarshan/Documents/WebDev/BrunelConnector/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:502:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sudarshan/Documents/WebDev/BrunelConnector/models/User.js:24:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sudarshan/Documents/WebDev/BrunelConnector/routes/api/users.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sudarshan/Documents/WebDev/BrunelConnector/server.js:13:23)
```

The schema is definitely present.
Also, there is no database referencing error as there is only one single schema.
The requirements are also specified in the correct order.
Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `string` to `mongoose.model`, when it needs to be the schema object itself:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: { type: String },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```